# How to load custom fonts instantly next js and prevent FOUT

Tags: time, next.js, fonts, load

I have a next JS application and my custom fonts are in my public folder.

My task is to prevent FOUT (flash of unstyled text) on site load and so I have settled for using `font-display:block;`

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
        src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-display:block;
    }
```

in `document.tsx` I am preloading the fonts in the `Head` component as such :

```
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.woff2"
  as="font"
  type="font/woff2"
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>
```

in `_app.tsx` I am importing global styles as such `import './styles.css';`

When i check load time for my fonts in the nextwork tab, it is roughly 3 seconds (please refer to screenshot).

[image]

Any suggestions on making my font load faster?

Comment: change  font-display:block; to  font-display:swap;

Comment: font-display:swap is causing flash of unstyled text and project owner does not want that :( ....they dont want to see defualt font while custom font is loading. @H9ee

Comment: @Loreen: as a last resort you could convert you font to a base64 encoded data url used in an inlined `@font-face` rule (so as inlined `<style>` block in your html head). This will bloat your HTML code quite a bit, but should prevent any FOUT. Otherwise you should also check, if your font could be cached efficiently (e.g by .htaccess/server config expiry rules)